# Email validation using jquery returns true even for invalid email

Tags: html, jquery, css, validation, email

i am trying to validate email address using JQuery but it always return true even for invalid email address.
this is the function.

```
 function check_email($email) {
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (!regex.test(email)) {
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
}
```

};

Here is the function which send parameter email to this function

```
function valid_email() {
var $email = $("#email").val();
if (check_email($email)) {
  $("#email").css("border", "1px solid green");
  $("#email").css("border", "1px solid green");
  $("#email_error_message").hide();
}
else {
  $("#email").css("border", "1px solid red");
  $("#email_error_message").show();
  $("#email_error_message").html("please provide a vallid email address");
}
```

}

Comment: Leave the email validation to `<input type="email" />` because your regex is going mark valid emails as actually invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your check_email function has a param named '$email' but uses 'email' internally.

Here's a corrected version (with some lightly simplified logic):

```js
function check_email(email) {
  var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return (regex.test(email))
};

function valid_email() {
  var $email = $("#email").val();
  if (check_email($email)) {
    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid green");
    $("#email_error_message").hide();
  } else {
    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid red");
    $("#email_error_message")
      .html("please provide a valid email address")
      .show();
  }
}

// fire it on change (which occurs on blur, not every keystroke)
$('#email').on('change', valid_email)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email">
<div id="email_error_message"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dnaiel Beck for your response.
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regex to validate emails. You can use a plain HTML5 email input and call `.checkValidity()` on it which will return `true` if valid and `false` if invalid.

```js
function valid_email() {
  var valid = $("#email")[0].checkValidity();
  if (valid) {
    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid green");
    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid green");
    $("#email_error_message").hide();
  } else {
    $("#email").css("border", "1px solid red");
    $("#email_error_message").show();
    $("#email_error_message").html("please provide a vallid email address");
  }
}

$("button").on("click", valid_email);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="email" id="email" />

<button>Check validity</button>
```

This has an advantage of

1. You outsource the email validation to the browser.
2. You avoid writing regular expression that disallow legitimate emails.